# Three.js Shader glass effect with PNG-image-mask on a Video-Texture

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, shader

some days ago I visited the site [activetheory.net](https://activetheory.net/) again. And I saw this stunning nice glass effect in the Homescreen logo border and tried to recode it. Based on the minified code I was able to see they use a PNG as a mask.

I was able to load a png inside the shader and show it up, also it was easy to get a mesh with video texture working. Now I'm stuck on the combining part (png with video) inside the shaders.

someone got experience with it and can help me?

Thank you and have a nice Day!

here is the shader-material part from:

```
var g = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(128.0, 72.0);
var outline = THREE.ImageUtils
    .loadTexture('outline.png');
outline.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
var mat = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
            map: {type: "t", value: movieScreen.texture},
            outline: {type: "t", outline},
            aspect: {type: "fv1", value: []},
            res: {type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)}
        },
    vertexShader: document.
    getElementById('vertShader').text,
    fragmentShader: document.
    getElementById('fragShader').text,
    transparent: true,
});
```

here are the shaders:

```
<script id="vertShader" type="shader">
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec2 nUv;

    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        nUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
</script>
<script id="fragShader" type="shader">

    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec2 nUv;

    uniform float color;
    uniform sampler2D outline;
    uniform sampler2D map;


    void main(void) {

        float alpha = step(0.9, texture2D(outline, vUv).a);

        gl_FragColor = texture2D(outline, nUv);
        gl_FragColor *= alpha;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: sue I edited the Question and added some code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a similar shader working. For everyone who is interested.

The shaders:

```
<script id="vertShader" type="shader">
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec2 nUv;

    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        nUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.05);
    }
</script>
<script id="fragShader" type="shader">

    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec2 nUv;

    uniform float color;
    uniform sampler2D outline;
    uniform sampler2D map;


    void main(void) {

        float alpha = step(0.9, texture2D(outline, vUv).a);

        gl_FragColor = texture2D(map, nUv);
        gl_FragColor *= alpha;
        gl_FragColor += 0.08 * alpha;
    }
</script>
```

Have fun!